# image path into sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm doing an user profile, first the user selects the picture and upload into a folder with this code, the image is displayed after is uploaded:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize variables
    string sSavePath;
    string sThumbExtension;
    int intThumbWidth;
    int intThumbHeight;

    // Set constant values
    sSavePath = "images/";
    sThumbExtension = "_thumb";
    intThumbWidth = 160;
    intThumbHeight = 120;

    // If file field isn’t empty
    if (filUpload.PostedFile != null)
    {
        // Check file size (mustn’t be 0)
        HttpPostedFile myFile = filUpload.PostedFile;
        int nFileLen = myFile.ContentLength;
        if (nFileLen == 0)
        {
            lblOutput.Text = "El archivo no fue cargado.";
            return;
        }

        // Check file extension (must be JPG)
        if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(myFile.FileName).ToLower() != ".jpg")
        {
            lblOutput.Text = "El archivo debe tener una extensión JPG";
            return;
        }

        // Read file into a data stream
        byte[] myData = new Byte[nFileLen];
        myFile.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, nFileLen);

        // Make sure a duplicate file doesn’t exist.  If it does, keep on appending an 
        // incremental numeric until it is unique
        string sFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(myFile.FileName);
        int file_append = 0;
        while (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename)))
        {
            file_append++;
            sFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myFile.FileName)
                             + file_append.ToString() + ".jpg";
        }

        // Save the stream to disk
        System.IO.FileStream newFile
                = new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename),
                                           System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        newFile.Write(myData, 0, myData.Length);
        newFile.Close();

        // Check whether the file is really a JPEG by opening it
        System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallBack =
                       new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
        Bitmap myBitmap;
        try
        {
            myBitmap = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename));

            // If jpg file is a jpeg, create a thumbnail filename that is unique.
            file_append = 0;
            string sThumbFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myFile.FileName)
                                                     + sThumbExtension + ".jpg";
            while (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sThumbFile)))
            {
                file_append++;
                sThumbFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myFile.FileName) +
                               file_append.ToString() + sThumbExtension + ".jpg";
            }

            // Save thumbnail and output it onto the webpage
            System.Drawing.Image myThumbnail
                    = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(intThumbWidth,
                                                 intThumbHeight, myCallBack, IntPtr.Zero);
            myThumbnail.Save(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sThumbFile));
            imgPicture.ImageUrl = sSavePath + sThumbFile;


            // Displaying success information
            lblOutput.Text = "El archivo fue cargado con exito!";

            // Destroy objects
            myThumbnail.Dispose();
            myBitmap.Dispose();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException errArgument)
        {
            // The file wasn't a valid jpg file
            lblOutput.Text = "No es un archivo .jpg valido";
            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(sSavePath + sFilename));
        }
    }
}
```

After that the user finish with the other fields of the profile (name, email, etc), there is a save button and is saved into the database with this:

This is the front code

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:pruebaConnectionString %>"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Curriculum(Nombre, Correo) VALUES (@TextBox1, @TextBox2)">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" DefaultValue="" Name="TextBox1" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" DefaultValue="" Name="TextBox2" PropertyName="Text" />                     
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Actually there are more fields, but to make it short i just copy the first 2, the nombre field is the only that cannot be null on the database

Code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
                SqlDataSource1.Insert();

        String strConn = "Data Source=TOSHI;Initial Catalog=prueba;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        string strQuery = "Insert into curriculum (imagen) values (@imgPicture)";
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgPicture", (imgPicture.ImageUrl == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)imgPicture.ImageUrl));
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
}
```

what now i'm trying to do is that when the user clicks the save button (or what is on the method button1_click), the image url is saved into the database on the field Imagen that is a varchar 50, but is not working, i get: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Nombre', table 'prueba.dbo.Curriculum'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

But if i leave the button1_click method with just SqlDataSource1.Insert(); the fields get saved onto the database.

Any idea how to save the image url onto the database? Hope i'm being clear with my explanation!

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to create a new record (in which canse you need to specify all of the values) or are you tring to update a record?

At the moment your code is trying to do an INSERT which will create a new record in the curriculum table, but you are only setting the 1 value. Maybe you want to do an UPDATE instead?

```
string strQuery = "UPDATE curriculum SET imagen = @imgPicture WHERE Nombre = ???";
```

Comment: Your are totally right!! it's update!! but what goes next to where nombre?

Comment: Now is working, i wrote this string strQuery = "UPDATE curriculum SET imagen = @imgPicture"; but updates ALL the records not only the one i'm inserting

Comment: You need to replace the ??? with the value of nombre that you just inserted, maybe TextBox1.Text?